# Right syntax for the foreign key in InstallScript

Tags: magento-2.1, database, best-practice, foreign-key

When I adding a **foreign key**, I write something like:

```
->addForeignKey(
    $installer->getFkName('my_table_name', 'website_id', 'store_website', 'website_id'),
    'website_id',
    'store_website',
    'website_id',
    Table::ACTION_CASCADE
)
```

But when table prefix is used, table name can be different from the base name. What should I do in this case? *Should I use the method `SchemaSetupInterface::getTable($tablename)` or Magento adds table prefix automatically?*

**PS:** with the `getTable` method it could look like this:

```
->addForeignKey(
    $installer->getFkName('my_table_name', 'website_id', 'store_website', 'website_id'),
    'website_id',
    $installer->getTable('store_website'), // << CHANGED
    'website_id',
    Table::ACTION_CASCADE
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of **SchemaSetupInterface::getTable($tablename)** is the right syntax for the foreign key in InstallScript. If you use that Magento2 checked table prefix if any and add that automatically.

Magento2 team also used that for all its core module.